# Can every order-preserving function $\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ be represented using only {AND, OR, TRUE, FALSE}?

Tags: logic, lattice-orders

Write $\mathbb{B} = \{0,1\}$ for the Boolean domain. Then those functions $\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ representable by an expression in the language of bounded distributive lattices are necessarily order-preserving.

Does the converse hold?

Just to be completely explicit, I want to know: can every order-preserving function $\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ be represented by an expression involving only the operators {AND, OR, TRUE, FALSE}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For every collection of variables that when set to 1 cause the function to return 1, form a clause that is the AND of all these variables, and then take the OR of all these clauses.

Clearly, every input that should return 1 does return 1. Every input that should return 0 by the order-preserving property necessarily does not contain among its 1-valued variables any subset that cause the function to return 1, so it does not satisfy any of the clauses of the OR I gave.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. How would you represent **not** with just **and**, **or**, **true**, and **false**?  I.e., for a boolean variable $v$, what expression using just $v$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\top$, and $\bot$ will have the value $\lnot v$?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: **not** is not (by my understanding of the term) order-preserving, since $0 < 1$ but $\mathbf{not}(0) > \mathbf{not}(1)$.

Comment: Oh—I completely missed the bit about order-preserving!

Comment: Do you even need AND or FALSE?

Comment: @RahulNarain: arguably the constant-zero function is order preserving (so I guess I do need FALSE).

Comment: @Willemien: I need AND. Think of the function on three variables that is $1$ exactly when at least two of the inputs are $1$. I claim I can't make such a function using only OR.